# Salvando relatório no disco em PDF

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Peguei um código legado aqui e ainda por cima não tenho experiência com WindowsForms.

O caso é, um relatório é gerado e salva dentro de um objeto do tipo PrintDocument.

Depois parece que ele popula outro objeto, do tipo PrintPriviewDialog, e já chama o dialog da impressão que aparece o relatório na tela.

O que preciso é apenas de não chamar nada e salvar o PDF no disco do PrintDocument, como?

Comment: Pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código?

Answer (score 0):

Ele chama a dialog porque precisa que escolhas a forma (software) de converter para PDF. Para o fazeres directamente tens que aceder a uma biblioteca que faça a escrita para PDF e normalmente terás que pagar por uma.

Podes encontrar um post que explica uma possível solução [aqui](https://www.nathanpjones.com/wp/2013/03/output-to-pdf-in-wpf-for-free/). Não testei mas parece ser exactamente o que procuras.

Comment: Então, acabou que utilizei a impressora padrão do windows mesmo em XPS e foi numa boa, demorei a perceber alguns parâmetros que tinham que ser setados e não sabia, vou colocar a solução aqui abaixo, mas vlw pelo link!

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi com alguns parâmetros que estavam faltando em vários tutoriais que achei e outras respostas aqui no StackO, não sei por que exatamente nos dos caras funcionavam e no meu não, talvez seja alguma coisa relativa com versões.

Acabou que não verifiquei se era realmente necessário converter o Objeto de PrintDialog para PrintDocument, mas foi assim que fiz:

```
this.printDocumentFunciona = this.printDialog1.Document;
```

A implementação propriamente dita:

```
this.printDocumentFunciona.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer";
this.printDocumentFunciona.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
this.printDocumentFunciona.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "NomeArquivo.xps";

this.printDocumentFunciona.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
this.printDocumentFunciona.Print();
```

Importante, se selecionar a Impressora do Foxit, não funciona de jeito nenhum, sempre aparece o dialog para escolher o nome, mas usando a impressora XPS do Windows ou a de PDF do Office/Windows, funciona sem abrir nada.